# Error when I installed Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 22.04, acpi

I want to dual-boot Ubuntu next to Windows 11. I have an Asus ROG Strix G15 G513RM laptop. I'm getting the following error messages. How can I solve this?

[image]

```
[    0.268581] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_TZ.TZ01], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326)
[    0.268598] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
[    0.270667] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162
[    0.270672] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
[    0.270675] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP2.WWAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)
[    0.270678] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
[    1.217836] hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err-19)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)