# Core i3-10105F CPU and NVIDIA GT 730 GPU always gets error messages when booting

Tags: nvidia, acpi, nvidia-geforce, sgx

Ubuntu 20.04 boot screen:

[image]

Info about the computer: 8 gigs of RAM, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS,gnome type 3.36.8 It's pretty slow as I only use it for movies. Also lately with the error messages I realized that I can't even update the computer.

Comment: What makes you believe this is related to you not being able to watch movies? How do you want to watch movies?

Comment: The file-system check messages stand out to me... ie. either the machine wasn't shutdown correctly, or it needs some diagnostics to check for issues... I'd perform standard hardware checks on the device as the sda2 issues are where I'd start (ie. ram test, motherboard cap-check, disk health using SMART etc).. You haven't given any indicators as to what normal boot messages are; only showing what is there now... how does what you see in your pasted image differ to before you were worried about it?

Comment: Check BIOS Battery !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: `Also lately with the error messages I realized that I can't even update the computer.` What are the outputs of the commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`?