# ACPI BIOS Error: Could not resolve symbol

Tags: bios

My system is a Dell Latitude 5430 laptop. I was happily running the latest version of Ubuntu before saying a BIOS update was available. Stupid me applied the update and now I get the attached error.

I can boot to recovery mode. I tried a few suggestions after googling for similar issues, but unfortunately it still remains.

[image]

Comment: No unfortunately, thanks though!

Comment: Please be specific with details; if you're using the *latest* why not just say Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop, or Ubuntu 23.04 Server?

Comment: Sorry, desktop 23.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)