# Ubuntu boot problem, I think it's partition

Tags: partitioning, uefi, boot-repair, gpt

After I chose Ubuntu in grub 2.06 I saw this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Does it eventually boot afterwards?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the partition?

Comment: ACPI errors are not normally a problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot

Your root partition reports as clean. If your system boots and works normally there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: The problem is system doesn't boot eventually and don't work normally, and stay at this screen.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. This may also be helpful, to get it to boot. Edit grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rhgb acpi_enforce_resources=lax pcie_ports=compat" as this partly ignores ACPI and should get you to boot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finally find the solution.
Ubunto's shell can't match by my graphic cart.
I set it on my graphic cart "rtx3050ti" in recovery mood,and problem solved.