# Error messages during boot: ACPI BIOS Error

Tags: boot

on a new installation of Ubuntu 22.04.3 I receive some error messages every time on boot which I made a picture of (is there a way to copy the messages from some log file?): [Picture of boot message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMxx1.jpg)

According to some other threads here:
[ACPI error messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367947/acpi-error-messages-during-boot)
[ACPI BIOS Error messages when booting Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299214/acpi-bios-error-messages-when-booting-ubuntu-20-04)

this isn't a real issue but it feels strange to boot with these error messages and I'd like to try to fix them.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any other solution on the internet.

Does anyone have an idea I can try?

Thanks,
Patrick